# Google Calendar invitations sent to Office 365 users bypass the inbox (no email notification)?

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365

I have an Office 365 account that I use only for email. **Problem**: Whenever a third party sends me a **Google** calendar invitation, it never arrives in my Outlook 365 inbox.

Today I discovered that all those Google invitations land directly on my Office 365 Calendar, which I have never used (and don't need to use).

Is there a way to configure things (as a user) so I receive notifications in my Office 365 **inbox** when Google Calendar invites arrive? (You know, like every other email client does? :-)) I looked through Office 365 settings but didn't find a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a rule set up which automatically accepts invites?

Comment: No rules set up at all. Clever guess, though!

Comment: The invitations land on my Office 365 calendar, but the sender of the calendar invitations (from Google Calendar) never receives any acknowledgment of any acceptance. (My Office 365 Calendar entry reads: "You didn't respond.")

Comment: if you create a new account, send yourself an invite are you able to replicate? I wonder if it's something to do with the sender.

Comment: Yes, it replicates. I have tried sending calendar invitations to my Office 365 account from three different Google accounts. Also, dozens of my colleagues have sent me Google calendar invites for years and I never see them (presumably they all went to Office 365 calendar directly). Is this normal Office 365 behavior?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13087/sending-an-outlook-invitation-from-gmail - it would appear to be a known issue, or rather, something they know about without plans to resolve - likely due to it being a google vs microsoft issue

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that discussion is about the same issue (it's 8 years old, predating Office 365, and it seems to be about calendar-to-calendar compatibility, not about emails showing up). Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @DanB if you search for any recent invitation by its subject, are you able to find it anywhere? And please check whether it's in [recoverable items](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/recover-deleted-items-in-outlook-for-windows-49e81f3c-c8f4-4426-a0b9-c0fd751d48ce).

Comment: @robdy: Thanks, but nothing comes up in search, and nothing in deleted items, trash, junk mail, clutter, or any other similar mailbox. My account has no recoverable items capability. Thanks though!

Comment: Ok and do you have access to Exchange Admin Center so you can search for emails server-side?

Comment: @robdy: Nope, I am just an end-user of Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the desktop client to read your mails or just the Outlook Web Access? I guess there's no setting in the webclient, but in the desktop application under 
Options - Calendar - AutoAccept.

See also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoU1lPGsqLc) for instructions...

With the autoaccept setting turned on the google calender invites are automatically added to the calendar and the email (which surley is received) is deleted (and can be found under deleted items)..

Comment: Using OWA. I'll check it out!

Comment: I tried the Windows desktop client and found the option. It was unchecked, meaning NOT to autoaccept. Just for grins, I checked the option, saved, unchecked, the option, and saved again. Then sent a test invitation from Google Calendar. No change in behavior: still no email notification, and the invitation landed silently on the Office 365 calendar in an "unaccepted" state. Not tentative.